# Rails 6 deployed on Heroku won't update Stylesheets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-6

I built a Rails 6 app and deployed it to Heroku. But any changes I make to the stylesheet are not reflected. All the Heroku documentation and SO questions/answers appear to no longer be relevant to the current Rails setup in this regard. I could precompile the assets before pushing to heroku but I'd prefer not to. And actually I did find a "solution" but it feels more like a hack than a real solution. If I open config/initializers/assets.rb and change the statement:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

to

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.1'
```

then it will update the assets. But that means if I am experimenting with the look of the site I would be changing the version all the time. I mean if that's they way it's supposed to work I'll live with it, but it doesn't seem right. Anyone know a way to get Heroku to just update it on every push?

Answer (score 0):

You've to compile the assets from the heroku end(i.e. in your server on Heroku), so after pushing your code to Heroku, run:

```
$ heroku run rake assets:precompile
# If above doesn't work
$ heroku run RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

Also, it's a good practice to add `public/assets`(or whatever folder that precompiles to) folder to your `.gitignore` file, so incase if you precompile assets in your local environment this will not mess up with your production env when you push to Heroku. But everytime you change some CSS and push to heroku, you'll need to precomile assets on Heroku end from the above command.

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those worked. Or more precisely Heroku does seem to be precompiling the assets per the logs but it is somehow precompiling the older version of them. Only when I change the asset version number does it take any changes into account, although in development it does take them into account. This is a new issue with Rails 6 as my Rails 5 apps never had this issue.

Comment: Did you first delete your `public/assets/` folder and then included `public/assets` in your `.gitignore` file?

Comment: There isn't a public/assets folder in the project.

Comment: Hey @SteveCarey, just wondering if you remember getting a solution to this? Having issues with scss files not being update in heroku with Rails 6. Pain in the ****!

Comment: @Bradley Well I don't want to tell you the wrong thing cuz it's been a while. But I think what I ended up doing was precompiling the assets locally in my dev environment, then pushing the precompiled assets to Heroku.